# Typescript try catch function with generics

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make one line try catch function which accepts promise and generic type.
But when I use my function my generic type doesn't show my generic type

Object is of type 'unknown'.ts(2571)

Instead of showing {type: string}

Here is the function

```js
export const tcatch = async <T extends unknown> (promise: Promise<any>) => {
  try {
    const tcData = await promise;
    return [tcData as T, null];
  } catch (tcError) {
    return [null, tcError];
  }
};
```

And here is the usage

```js
const promise = WebBrowser.openAuthSessionAsync();
const [data, error] = await tcatch<{type: string}>(promise);
```

Comment: "doesn't work" is not an adequate description of a problem. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Typescript has update changed object inside catch to type `unknown` instead of `any`
so this

```js
export const tcatch = async <T extends unknown> (promise: Promise<any>) => {
  try {
    const tcData = await promise;
    return [tcData as T, null];
  } catch (tcError) {
    return [null, tcError];
  }
};
```

actually looks like this:

```js
export const tcatch = async <T extends unknown> (promise: Promise<any>) => {
  try {
    const tcData = await promise;
    return [tcData as T, null];
  } catch (tcError:unknown) {
    return [null, tcError];
  }
};
```

that is why you getting object of type unknown to solve this you need to change it to your own interface / type or change it to `any`.

In your case just add this inside the catch:

```js
  const urType  = tcError as YourInterfaceOrType
```

OR change to this `catch(tcError:any)`

Comment: What if I want to type my data and error ?
I changed it to this

export const tcatch = async <T = unknown>(promise: Promise<any>) => {
  try {
    const tcData = await promise;
    return [tcData as T, null];
  } catch (tcError) {
    return [null, tcError as T];
  }
};

But of course error cant be the same as data

Comment: There's no way of declaring the type of thrown values at the moment. That's why the previous default behavior of `tcError: any` is considered unsafe now and was replaced by `tcError: unknown`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how correct this solution is but I ended up with this one

```js
export const tcatch = async <DataType, ErrorType>(
  promise: Promise<any>,
): Promise<[DataType | null, ErrorType | null]> => {
  try {
    const tcData = await promise;
    return [tcData as DataType, null];
  } catch (tcError) {
    return [null, tcError as ErrorType];
  }
};

// And then use it next

const [data, error] = await tcatch<{type: string}, {error_type: string}>(authSessionPromise);

const my_data = data?.type;
const my_error = error?.error_type;
```